# Why is my mv renaming for a directory not working?

Tags: mac-osx, unix, lion

```
$ mv 'Assignments' 'assignments'
mv: cannot move `Assignments' to a subdirectory of itself, `assignments/Assignments'
```

Trying to rename `Assignments` directory to `assignments`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OSX HFS+ filesystem is case-insensitive, so it's interpreting `Assignments` and `assignments` as the same name. I would try:

```
$ mv Assignments tempdir
$ mv tempdir assignments
```

Answer (score 4):

you are working with a filesystem which is not case sensitive (though it is case preserving).  So when you say `mv Assignments assignments`, it is as if you are saying `mv Assignments Assignments/assignments`.  Instead try renaming it to something else first.

Answer (score -1):

The nuclear option is to start from scratch on this hard drive partition and OS installation by enabling OS X's Mac OS Extended (Journaled, case-sensitive) option. Be aware that this requires a complete reformatting of the disk and will clobber everything on the affected partition.

Another caveat is that certain applications in OS X do not place nicely with case-sensitive file systems. (At the time of this writing, I believe Steam is one of them.)

I just wanted to make readers of this question aware that this option does exist.

--

I personally resist the idea of the intermediary step and prefer to use the Finder to make such a change. It will not complain about the change if you rename the folder or file by just changing case.